# Saving to MongoDB with Node/Express/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

I am trying to save a new "playlist" to mongoDB using a combo of node/express/bodyParser/mongoose. Here is the code I have so far:

```
router.route('/playlists')

// create a playlist (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/playlists)
.post(function(req, res) {

    var playlist = new Playlist({});      // create a new instance of the Playlist model
    playlist.businessName = req.body.businessName;
    playlist.businessEmail = req.body.businessEmail;

    // save the playlist and check for errors
    playlist.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: playlist.businessName + " created a playlist with email - " + playlist.businessEmail + " - " + playlist });
    });

});
```

When I use POSTMAN to post I get the following response:

```
"message": "Test Business created a playlist with email - test@gmail.com - { __v: 0, _id: 55aff6c368f7d3ac2f000001 }"
```

The playlist.businessName and playlist.businessEmail are both getting returned like I expected, however these are not showing up in the database or in just the playlist response.  Only the following is showing up in the database when I post:

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55aff680551ec57031000001"
    },
    "__v": 0
}

However when I remove one of the key:value pairs and change the a little like the following it works:

```
router.route('/playlists')

// create a playlist (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/playlists)
.post(function(req, res) {

    var playlist = new Playlist({});      // create a new instance of the Playlist model
    playlist.name = req.body.businessName;
    //playlist.businessEmail = req.body.businessEmail;

    // save the playlist and check for errors
    playlist.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: playlist.name + " created a playlist - " + playlist });
    });

});
```

Data in database/document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "55aff94e214389d83c000001"
},
"name": "Test Business",
"__v": 0
```

}

The playlist.name is now showing up in the document.  my question is how would I go about saving playlist.name and playlist.email and more to the document?

**UPDATE**

Everything is now working as intended after updating the Schema.

Old Schema:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var PlaylistSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Playlist', PlaylistSchema);
```

Updated Schema:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var PlaylistSchema   = new Schema({
    businessName: String,
    businessEmail: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Playlist', PlaylistSchema);
```

Comment: How did you define your model `Playlist`?

Comment: It sounds like the schema definition is the issue. Please post the schema for `Playlist`.

Comment: Ah, thanks guys you directed me to the issue.  I had the schema defined in another file and didn't think to look there.